# Taking limit of a probability distribution

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I have a probability distribution of the form

$$ p_{m+1}(s)= \frac {(bs)^m}{b(m!)} e^{-bs}$$

I want to show that under the limit $m \to \infty$, it will becomes a Gaussian.

I applied Stirling's formula on the factorial but I can't massage the expression into the form I want. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It will not become a Gaussian because you have $e^{-bs}$ and not $e^{-bs^2}$ as in the Gaussian. You need the $s^2$ in the exponent.

Comment: But it was in my homework problem. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Have you copied correctly? can you check it again please?

Comment: I am quite sure that it is copied correctly... I have sent an email to my TA about this, he haven't replied yet

Comment: Moreover I think that if you sum up all the terms for m=0,1,2,... you will get $\frac{1}{b}$ instead of $1$. Have you checked that?

Comment: m is not the r.v.

Answer (score 1):

I too think there is an issue with the density (I think the $b$ should be in the numerator, not the denominator) but essentially this is the density of a Gamma distribution with mean $\frac{m+1}{b}$ and variance $\frac{m+1}{b^2}$.

It represents the distribution of the sum of $m+1$ iid exponential random variables with rate parameter $b$, so with mean $\frac1b$ and standard deviation $\frac1b$.  So as $m+1$ increases, the central limit theorem applies and so (strictly speaking with some scale and location adjustments) the distribution approaches a normal distribution.  For me that is enough.

If that was insufficient, you could find the characteristic function of the Gamma distribution and show that that (again with some adjustment) converges on the characteristic function of a normal distribution.